# How to round values based on rows in R?

Tags: r, rounding

I'm wondering whether there is a clean way to round values differently based on row conditions. An example of the dataset I'm using is below where I want to round columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4` based on `var`. For example, I want to round to 2 decimal places unless `var` equals `var1|var2|var3` where I want to round to 3 decimal places instead. Is this doable? Thanks.

```
set.seed(10)

dat <- data.frame(      
  vel = rep(c("slo", "med", "fas"), each = 28),
  var = rep(paste0("var", 1:7), times = 12),
  col1 = rnorm(84, 0.03, 0.08),
  col2 = rnorm(84, 0.03, 0.08),
  col3 = rnorm(84, 0.03, 0.08),
  col4 = rnorm(84, 0.03, 0.08)     
)
```

Comment: Do you want to *present* the data to varying degrees of precision or to *edit* the values themselves?  If the former, haw are you presenting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) 

dat %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(col1:col4, ~ case_when(
    var %in% c("var1", "var2", "var3") ~ round(.x, 3),
    TRUE ~ round(.x, 2)
  )))

# A tibble: 84 x 6
# Rowwise: 
   vel   var     col1   col2   col3   col4
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 slo   var1   0.031  0.065  0.045 -0.087
 2 slo   var2   0.015  0.043 -0.085 -0.042
 3 slo   var3  -0.08   0.083 -0.061 -0.024
 4 slo   var4  -0.02   0.21   0      0.12 
 5 slo   var5   0.05  -0.06   0.04  -0.03 
 6 slo   var6   0.06   0.02   0.11  -0.06 
 7 slo   var7  -0.07   0     -0.02  -0.06 
 8 slo   var1   0.001  0.015  0.132 -0.051
 9 slo   var2  -0.1    0.036  0.048  0.063
10 slo   var3   0.009  0.122  0.005  0.068
# ... with 74 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tom. I'm getting some trailing zeros on the values that have been rounded to 2 decimal places. Is there a way to avoid this so they don't read like they're expressed to 3?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `digits` parameter is vectorized which makes this easy.

```
dat[, paste0(names(dat)[-(1:2)], "rounded")] <-
  lapply(dat[, -(1:2)], round, 
         digits = ifelse(dat$var %in% c("var1", "var2", "var3"), 3, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `across` to specify all columns that `starts_with` the string "col" for rounding, and use `ifelse` to choose which row to `round`. Since the condition in each row is different, we need to include `rowwise` at the start of the piping chain.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  rowwise() %>%  
  mutate(across(starts_with("col"), 
                ~ifelse(var %in% c("var1", "var2", "var3"), 
                        round(.x, digits = 3), 
                        round(.x, digits = 2)))) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 84 × 6
   vel   var     col1   col2   col3   col4
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 slo   var1   0.031  0.065  0.045 -0.087
 2 slo   var2   0.015  0.043 -0.085 -0.042
 3 slo   var3  -0.08   0.083 -0.061 -0.024
 4 slo   var4  -0.02   0.21   0      0.12 
 5 slo   var5   0.05  -0.06   0.04  -0.03 
 6 slo   var6   0.06   0.02   0.11  -0.06 
 7 slo   var7  -0.07   0     -0.02  -0.06 
 8 slo   var1   0.001  0.015  0.132 -0.051
 9 slo   var2  -0.1    0.036  0.048  0.063
10 slo   var3   0.009  0.122  0.005  0.068
# … with 74 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case

```
iii=dat$var %in% c("var1","var2","var3")
ccc=grepl("col",colnames(dat))

dat[iii,ccc]=round(dat[iii,ccc],3)
dat[!iii,ccc]=round(dat[!iii,ccc],2)
```